# What do these [Greek alphabet] forms in the OED signify?

Tags: dictionaries

I underlined them in red beneath. [Screenshot](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/215075?redirectedFrom=unless#eid16548570):

[image]

Comment: Please don't link to sites that require subscriptions.  The link fails unless one is a subscriber.

Comment: Also, please don't post pictures of text.  It can't be searched, it's unfriendly to users with vision problems or slow internet connections, and it doesn't add anything to the question.  There's no reason you can't  paste stuff like **α, β, γ** in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It refers back to the section **Forms**

The word *unless* has a rather complex history as a word. In Middle English there are various expressions *of lesse*, *of lasse*, *on lesse"  "not upon lesse thann" and so on. The OED calls these different spellings of *unless* "forms" and enumerates them by Greek letters. It describes the origin of each "form". Click on the "... show more" link to see the list of Middle English forms.

In modern English, all these forms have been merged into a single word *unless*.

This is a particular usage for the OED, not in general use in English.